# Makefile not finding other classes (Java, Linux, Ubuntu)

Tags: java, linux, makefile

I am trying to create a makefile for my classes but it seems like the
makefile cannot see or find my classes although they are in same
folder.

It works when I run javac but not when I run the makefile.

Makefile

```
JAVAC=/usr/bin/javac
dir=src/myrepo

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:

        $(JAVAC) -cp . $< 

default: $(dir)/*.class 

clean: 
        if [ -e $(dir)/*.java~ ] ; then rm $(dir)/*.java~; fi 
        mv $(dir)/*.class bin; fi
```

Directories are `Assignment/Makefile`, `Assignment/src/myrepo` (All classes in myrepo)

Classes are `PrintIt.java`, `BinarySearchTree.java`, `BinaryTree.java`, `Record.java` (All in myrepo)

Error:

```
/usr/bin/javac -cp . src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java 
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public class BinarySearchTree extends BinaryTree {
                                      ^
  symbol: class BinaryTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        public void insert ( Record d ){
                             ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        public void insert ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                             ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        public void insert ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                       ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        public void insert ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                      ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> find ( Record d ){
                                             ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> find ( Record d ){
               ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:30: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> find ( Record d ){
                              ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> find ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                             ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> find ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                       ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> find ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                                      ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> find ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
               ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> find ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                              ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
        public void delete ( Record d ){
                             ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> delete ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                               ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> delete ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                         ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> delete ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> delete ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
               ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> delete ( Record d, BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                              ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> findMin ( BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> findMin ( BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                               ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> findMin ( BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
               ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> findMin ( BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                              ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> removeMin ( BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> removeMin ( BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                                                                 ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> removeMin ( BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
               ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
        public BinaryTreeNode<Record> removeMin ( BinaryTreeNode<Record> node ){
                              ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
            if (root == null)
                ^
  symbol:   variable root
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                root = new BinaryTreeNode<Record> (d, null, null);
                ^
  symbol:   variable root
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                root = new BinaryTreeNode<Record> (d, null, null);
                           ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
                root = new BinaryTreeNode<Record> (d, null, null);
                                          ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
                insert (d, root);
                           ^
  symbol:   variable root
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                    node.left = new BinaryTreeNode<Record> (d, null, null);
                                    ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
                    node.left = new BinaryTreeNode<Record> (d, null, null);
                                                   ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                        node.right = new BinaryTreeNode<Record> (d, null, null);
                                         ^
  symbol:   class BinaryTreeNode
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                        node.right = new BinaryTreeNode<Record> (d, null, null);
                                                        ^
  symbol:   class Record
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
            if (root == null)
                ^
  symbol:   variable root
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
                return find (d, root);
                                ^
  symbol:   variable root
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
            root = delete (d, root);
            ^
  symbol:   variable root
  location: class BinarySearchTree
src/myrepo/BinarySearchTree.java:48: error: cannot find symbol
            root = delete (d, root);
                              ^
  symbol:   variable root
  location: class BinarySearchTree
40 errors
Makefile:12: recipe for target 'src/myrepo/*.class' failed
make: *** [src/myrepo/*.class] Error 1
```

Comment: try "dir=/src/myrepo". Seems like u r missing forward slash.

Comment: It seems the classpath is wrong. You use the current directory but shouldn't it be "./src"? Assuming myrepo is a package name.

Comment: You should also consider to use a Java specific build tool like Maven, Gradle or Ant. Make and Java are not best friends.

Comment: @pavanc when I change it to "dir=/src/myrepo" it can't find my classes:    make: *** No rule to make target '/src/myrepo/*.class, needed by 'default'. Stop.

Comment: @vanje "./src" gave same error and when I made it "./src/myrepo" it gave original error. Also I must use a makefile in my assignment. Myrepo is my git repository - maybe that is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
# Assignment 1 makefile
# Hendri Vermeulen
# 29 March 2017

JAVAC=/usr/bin/javac
dir=src/myrepo

.SUFFIXES: .java .class

.java.class:
        $(JAVAC) -cp src/myrepo $< 

default: $(dir)/Record.class $(dir)/BinaryTree.class $(dir)/BinarySearchTree.cla

clean: 
        if [ -e $(dir)/*.java~ ] ; then rm $(dir)/*.java~; fi 
        mv $(dir)/*.class bin; fi
```

Had to add "-cp src/myrepo" with the compile command, the directory of my classpath.